# onClickListener onclicklistener Android Java programming

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclicklistener

When i click on the images it doesnt change the display textview, where did i go wrong?

```
    **List<ImageView> fields = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        try{
            id = R.id.class.getField("square" + (i+1)).getInt(0);
            views.add((ImageView)findViewById(id));
            ((View) fields).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View fields) {
                    for(int i=0; i < 64; i++)
                    {
                        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        display.setText("square" + i);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

    }**

}
```

}

Comment: what does it display? square63?

Comment: use `display.append(" \n square" + i);` to check textview text is updating or not

Comment: it should display the square clicked. it's a chess game where i got 64squares. example if i click the first square it should show square1 and the last square63

Comment: as zymurgeek has mentioned , you are doing wrong operation on list. By catching exception you are suppressing the error that you could have easily identified. So donot catch generic exception

Comment: Managed to solve it Zymurgeeks answer worked i was just displaying it wrong so i didnt see that it actually worked. So thx alot!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're adding the `onClick listener to the ArrayList of views`, not the image you added.  Change

```
 ((View) fields).setOnClickListener
```

to

```
 findViewById(id).setOnClickListener
```

Comment: Hi thx for the help but after i did what you said it is clickable but it only shows square63 on every square i click. what i want the OnClickListener to do is show square1 if i click square1 and so on.

Comment: There's another issue in the code.  For each click, it iterates through 0-63 setting the text for the clicked image 64 times.  So you only see the last set which is "square 63".  In your loop, you need to compare the `fields` passed to `onClick` to the items in your `ArrayList` to see which image was clicked, then only issue a `setText` for the found item.